# How can I pull in column values based on if a field value matches column name?

Tags: sql

I'm trying to write some code where I can join two tables and pull in a column based on if a field matches the name of a column.

For Example,

Table A has a column named index -- which has values such (IG,HY). I'm trying to join table A to table B -- which has column names(IG,HY). I want to pull in the columns of B based on whether or not the values of the column in A matches the name of the column in B.

How do I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Pick either SQL Server or MySQL

Comment: For SQL Server, check out sys.objects and sys.columns. You'll have to join to those, specifically sys.columns.name where sys.objects.name = 'YourTableName'.

Comment: I removed the DBMS specific tags. Feel free to add back the one that you are actually using.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to use a convoluted logic like below.  The below logic retrieves the values `TableA` and makes a dynamic SQL to select them from `TableB`.

```
CREATE TABLE #TableA 
(
   ColumnName VARCHAR(10)
)

INSERT INTO #TableA VALUES ('IG'),('HY')

SELECT * FROM #TableA

CREATE TABLE #TableB
(
   IG VARCHAR(10),
   HY VARCHAR(10)
)

INSERT INTO #TableB VALUES( '1', 'A'), ('2', 'B')

SELECT * FROM #TableB

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(100)

SET @sql = 'SELECT ' + STUFF(
                    (
                        SELECT ',' + ColumnName
                        FROM #TableA
                        FOR XML PATH('')
                    ), 1, 1, '') +
            ' FROM #TableB'

EXEC(@sql)

DROP TABLE #TableA
DROP TABLE #TableB
```